# Select all "li" that do NOT contain a "ul" within

Tags: javascript, jquery, categories

I'm building a nested drop down navigation for products and I want to automatically hide any categories that are empty.

Unfortunately server side language does not allow efficient way of doing this, so I thought I could output number of products each category has directly, then use jQuery to remove any empty nodes.

I want to target only the `li`'s within `nav#top_nav`:

```
 <nav id="top_nav">
   <nav class="nav1">
     <ul>
       <li data-num-products="0">
         <a href="...">AAA</a>
         <ul>
            <li data-num-products="3"><a href="...">BBB</a></li>
            <li data-num-products="0"><a href="...">CCC</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
       <li data-num-products="7"><a href="">DDD</a></li>

     </ul>
   <nav>
 </nav>
```

Given 1 level of nesting `ul`'s, I want to remove any `li`'s that...

- have no nested `ul`'s within them and
- have `data-num-products == 0`.

So in the example above `AAA` is retained because it has `ul` children, but `CCC` is removed because it has no `ul` children and no products.

UPDATE:

It might require 2 passes of removal because if a li contains a ul whose li elements are all removed, then we'll want to remove the ul too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#top_nav li[data-num-products='0']").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).children("ul").length === 0; 
}).remove();
```

Comment: I select this one as the best answer for it's readibility.  ultimately I needed two passes like this: //first pass
$("#top_nav li[data-online-products='0']").filter(function() { return $(this).children("ul").length === 0; }).remove();
$("#top_nav ul").filter(function(){return $(this).children("li").length === 0;}).remove();
//2nd pass
$("#top_nav li[data-online-products='0']").filter(function() { return $(this).children("ul").length === 0; }).remove();

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "#top_nav li").filter( function(){
    return !this.getElementsByTagName("ul").length && !+this.getAttribute("data-num-products");
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X2D7y/

This will only remove if there are no UL descendants AND have attribute value of 0

Comment: You may want to change `!+this.getAttribute("data-num-products");` to something more explicit. If there are any `li` elements without that attribute, or with that attribute, but that do not successfully coerce to a number, the `!+` will be `true`.

Comment: @amnotiam if there is no data-num-products it will be same as having data-num-products 0.

Comment: That's what I mean. OP wants to remove elements with `data-num-products="0"`, but a `li` without that attribute will behave as though it has it because `!+null // true`, and so will be removed.

Comment: @amnotiam yes that's what I mean also: no attribute, no products, get removed. :D

Comment: I see what you mean, but I just meant that if there end up being `li` elements that are included for other purposes. An explicit test would be a little safer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('#top_nav li[data-num-products="0"]:not(:has(ul))').remove();
```

The selector breakdown is...

```
'#top_nav'                // start at element with "top_nav" id
' '                       // and select descendant...
'li'                      // li elements...
'[data-num-products="0"]' //   ...where attribute "data-num-products" is "0"
':not('                   //   ...but exclude li elements that...
  ':has(ul)'              //        ...have descendant ul elements
')'
```

---

Regarding your updated question, just change `:not(:has(ul))` to `:not(:has(li))`.

```
$('#top_nav li[data-num-products="0"]:not(:has(li))').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4YFDd/

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll( '#top_nav li[data-num-products="0"]' );
for( var li = 0; li < lis.length; li++ ) { 
    !lis[li].getElementsByTagName( 'ul' ).length && lis[li].parentNode.removeChild( lis[li] );
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/2zS9B/